# Setting password for all installed applications in Android

Tags: java, android, android-activity

Firstly I tried to set password for one application only. I set password for Instagram. But it doesnot work. I used the following code.

LockAppMainActivity.java

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_lock_app_main);
    startService(new Intent(this, CreatedWith.class));
}
```

CreatedWith.java

```
public class CreatedWith extends IntentService {
    public CreatedWith() {
        super("CreatedWith");
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ActivityManager mActivityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> RunningTask = mActivityManager.getRunningTasks(1);
        ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo ar = RunningTask.get(0);
        String activityOnTop = ar.topActivity.getClassName();
        if(activityOnTop.equals("com.instagram.android")){
            Intent lockIntent = new Intent(this, LockScreen.class);
            lockIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            this.startActivity(lockIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

LockScreen.java
// Contains code for unlocking

But this code is not working. When I open Instagram, it is opening normally. No lockscreen is shown.

Thank you

Comment: you getting classname and comparing package name ... trying using getPackageName() instead of getClassName()

Comment: @Rohit  i m also failed to do so how u resolved your issue ?